# Delete all dataframes in dictionary of dataframes if any np.nan is present

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter a dictionary of dataframes. I want to completely remove any dataframe that has any occurrence of `np.nan`. Is this kind of logic possible with pandas?

```
for df in df_dict.values():
    df = df.isna().any().any()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do two `any` with `isna`

```
df.isna().any().any()
```

Get your new dict

```
d = {k: v for k, v in dct.iteritems() if ~(v.isna().any().any())}
```

A little bit more about the timing

```
s=pd.Series([1,np.nan,1,2,3,4,5]*1000)
%timeit ~(s.isna().any())
80.1 µs ± 838 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit s.notna().all()
124 µs ± 1.18 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new dictionary:

```
new_dict = {k:v for k, v in dictionary.items() if v.notna().all().all()}
```

Comment: Just want to share my experience with u ~ ~ If you can use `any` , do not use `all` ~ :-)

Comment: @YOBEN_S thank you will keep in mind :) i was worried about `~` , would be interested to see with the inverse. , also i was typing when you answered ..

Comment: inverse is just for the single True False Turn , should be very quick